# 0.5 displays as 0.5 even when I use round(0.5,2)

Tags: r, zero, digit

I have a number like 0.5, I would like to keep two digits in order to make the number 0.50. While the last digit is zero, so it always cannot appear.

I have used round(0.5,2) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cheat by using:

```
y <- 0.5
formatC(round(y,2),2,format="f")
```

Note that this changes to character. Hence, it's for display purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `sprintf`

```
y <- 0.5
sprintf("%0.2f", round(y, 2))

[1] "0.50"
```

EDIT: According to  Wojciech Sobala (below)

```
sprintf("%0.2f", y)
```

should be sufficient.

```
sprintf("%0.2f", 0.478)
[1] "0.48"
```

Comment: What does the sprintf("%0.2f",..) mean?? why %0.2f?

Comment: See `?sprintf`. m.n: Two numbers separated by a period, denoting the field width (m) and the precision (n).

Comment: you can simplify to sprintf("%0.2f",y). @user471448 f - fixed point, m.n - field width (m), the precision (n) (you can read this in R help, try ?sprintf)

Comment: @Wojciech Thanks - I didn't know if sprintf would round or truncate, so I played it safe.